# SQL Server key column + JSON FOR PATH

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to have a JSON with all columns excluding one which I would like to use as a key column to join with other tables. The result should be grouped by the key column.

```
SELECT
    GroupKey, -- Not in JSON
    Data_A, -- Regular JSON as with FOR JSON PATH
    Data_B, 
    Data_C, 
    ...
FROM 
    T
GROUP BY GroupKey
FOR JSON PATH
```

| GroupKey | JSON |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "[{...}]" |

Comment: IN SQL Server 2022 you can use `JSON_OBJECT` or `JSON_ARRAY`. In previous versions you need a subquery

Comment: Do you have multiple rows with same key?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of columns and feeling lazy, you could do the following:

```sql
select  object_id
,   json_modify((select so.* for json path), '$[0].object_id', null)
from    sys.objects so
```

The idea is to create a json of all columns and then remove the id column by using JSON_MODIFY. Note that this will have slightly worse performance than above solutions, but saves you some copy pasting